# Recurrence relation, unsigned stirling numbers of first kind

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, stirling-numbers

Given the recurrence relation:

$p(n,k)=\frac{p(n-1,k-1)}{n} + \frac{(n-1)p(n-1,k)}{n}$ for $n \geq 2$
$p(1,k)=\delta_{k,0}$, $~ p_{n,k} = 0$ for $k<0$

I want to deduce that my recurrence satiesfies a similar recurrence as the unsigned stirling numbers of first kind:
${n+1 \brack k} = n {n \brack k} + {n \brack k-1}$ with ${0 \brack 0}=1$ and ${n \brack 0} = {0 \brack n} = 0$ for $k>0, n>0$

But as obvious I got problems with the intial values, because ${1 \brack k} = \delta_{1,k}$. I also tried to adjust the stirling numbers so it fits the initial values of my recurrence, but then I get problems with recurrence at ${2 \brack 1}$, which should be 1.

Is there a way to fix this or should I try another approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a(n,k)=n!p(n,k)$. Then $a(1,0)=1$, $a(1,k)=0$ for $k>1$, $a(n,k)=0$ for $k<0$, and

$$a(n,k)=a(n-1,k-1)+(n-1)a(n-1,k)\;.$$

Here are a few values, with zeroes above the diagonal suppressed:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
n\backslash k&0&1&2&3&4\\ \hline
1&1\\
2&1&1\\
3&2&3&1\\
4&6&11&6&1\\
5&24&50&35&10&1
\end{array}$$

For the unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind we have the same recurrence,

$${n\brack k}={{n-1}\brack{k-1}}+(n-1){{n-1}\brack k}\;,$$

with initial values ${0\brack 0}=1$, ${n\brack 0}=0$ for $n>0$, ${0\brack k}=0$ for $k>0$, and ${n\brack k}=0$ for $k<0$.

Here are a few values, with zeroes above the diagonal suppressed:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
n\backslash k&0&1&2&3&4\\ \hline
0&1\\
1&0&1\\
2&0&1&1\\
3&0&2&3&1\\
4&0&6&11&6&1\\
5&0&24&50&35&10&1
\end{array}$$

The relationship is visually obvious:

$$a(n,k)={n\brack{k+1}}\tag{1}$$

for $n\ge 1$ and $k\ge 0$. And since $a(1,k)={1\brack{k+1}}$ for $k\ge -1$ and $a(n,-1)={n\brack 0}$ for $n\ge 1$, the fact that the $a(n,k)$ satisfy the same recurrence as the Stirling numbers of the first kind ensures that $(1)$ does indeed hold for $n\ge 1$ and $k\ge 0$. It follows that

$$p(n,k)=\frac1{n!}{n\brack{k+1}}\;.$$